# VB.NET Debug Button Disabled

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate. I have made a fairly long program which worked fine.
One day I find that the debug button was disabled and both the build and rebuild buttons do not work. I have tried opening the same project files in Visual Basic Express 2010 but still, the sane problem.

I don't really want to have to reinstall but I'm not even sure that that will fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of app? WCF, ASP, Windows Form, Web Site, DLL....

Answer (score 3):

Is there a startup project?  One project in the Solution Explorer should be in bold.  Right-click the executable project and select "Set as StartUp Project".  Additionally, open the Project Properties, Application tab, and ensure Application type is either "Windows Forms Applications" or "Console Application".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reset the setting of your Visual Studio Ultimate?

Type: (In your visual studio command prompt)
devenv /resetsettings

Answer (score 0):

Buttons disabled for just that program, or all programs?

I vaguely remember having a similar problem many years ago. Re-creating the project and solution files fixed it, I think (ie. create a new solution/project and import all the .vb files).

Another thing to check would be whether the compiled files have become read-only. Maybe VB.NET can't delete the old .EXEs

Comment: If I create a new project the debugging works fine. It's only in this project that it doesn't work. The only problem with creating a new project means that I have to import all the settings and resources which takes an effing long time cos I must have used 1000+ icons and 100s of 'settings'. But thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: Try closing the project, then moving the "My Project", "bin" and "obj" directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a test application. I think thats more difficult then making the application itself. In my personal opinion, your better off building the whole software in a notepad.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx